# Run informatica load with automatic date increment

Tags: date-range, informatica

I need to create an on demand task to load data for say one month, with date increasing automatically by 1 everytime, till it reaches the month end date. 
The data of next date depends on the previous data, so i cant't give the date range and run them altogather. It should load for next date only when previous date data is loaded.
EG: starting from 1 april, it should load dat for 1 april, then automatically increment the date by 1, load data for 2 april, and so on.

Someone please help, how this can be done.
If possible, I would prefer to load data in a single session run, instead of running it multiple times.

Comment: can you explain what you meant by "The data of next date depends on the previous data"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mapping variable to keep track of the current date. Initialize the mapping variable with the beginning date using parameter file. In your mapping set the variable to the next day using the SETVARIABLE function. So, when you rerun the mapping the new value of the date will be used.

However, you have to run the mapping multiple times, which you can do using a shell/batch script.